# Issue with IBM MQ failing with create object

Tags: .net, vb.net, activex, ibm-mq

Having trouble with Ibm mq to load it in 64-bit windows machines.

```
Dim objMQ As Object
objMQ=CreateObject("MQAX200.MQSession")
```

I get

> "Cannot create ActiveX component."

in 64-bit machines and it works fine in  32-bit machines OS.

My question is  how do i alter the above piece of code to work in 64-bit OS?

Answer (score 4):

On Windows 7 64 bit, that piece of code works fine for me. I am using MQ v7.1 though.

Is there a specific reason you want to use MQAX200? There have been no updates to this interface for a long time. Instead of MQAX200, you can use the MQ .NET interface which is more up to date and has much more features than MQAX200.

MQ .NET interface is shipped in "amqmdnet.dll" assembly and can be found in "bin" folder of your MQ installation. There is only one assembly that works for both 32 and 64 bit architecture. You just need to reference "amqmdnet" in your project. There are also number of samples under "\tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base" folder.

Edit: Sample code:

```
            properties = new Hashtable();
            properties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
            properties.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
            properties.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channelName);

            MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager (queueManagerName,
                                                              properties);
            queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, 
                                       MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);
```

Comment: I wish I could vote more than once. ;-) It might also be worth noting that the up-to-date client that contains this assembly lives at [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75) (preferred) or [SupportPac MQC71](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC71).

Comment: @Shashi - Thanks for your info, It will be nice if you share me(if you know) how to use this amqmdnet.dll in the code with regard to objMQ=CreateObject("MQAX200.MQSession").

Comment: Please see the edit for sample code. You can find the same sample in SimplePut.cs source file under tools\dotnet\samples\cs\base folder.

Comment: Thanks Shashi, i will check that, however i installed version 7.1.0.0, it really didn't work for CreateObject("MQAX200.MQSession") as it threw the same exception(cannot create ActiveX component). My computer is windows 7, 64-bit OS.